# Is it necessary to use router installation disk on a new computer?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, installation, router

I have a Linksys WRT54G2 wireless router set up on my home network. When I first got the router, I used the installation disk on my desktop PC to set up my wireless network. I am getting rid of this computer, as I now have a laptop computer. The laptop can already utilize the network, and I can even configure the router using the laptop. Obviously, the old desktop doesn't even have to be turned on for any other laptops or devices to use the network.

If I get rid of the old desktop, will it be necessary to run the installation disk that came with the router on my new primary PC? Or is that a **one time process** to configure the router with the modem and set up a network?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to use the CD for the router to function properly, usually these CDs just contain a simplified utility to configure the router, and/or may install some junk programs that may (annoyingly) override stuff like WZC, which I wouldn't recommend.

I wouldn't say *don't* use the disk, it may have useful utilities on it, but I have never encountered a router that actually straight out *required* the use of the disk prior to installation.

Answer (score 4):

No, most of the time installation discs just make it easier to get you connected to the Internet when installing a new wireless router, I never use them myself, I configure everything manually.

In general it is not a bad thing to use the disc, I am old school and like to configure it myself.

Answer (score 4):

It is not required period, it is for your convenience and to help non-technical users connect. This **doesn't** stand for all makes and models as some can be extremely tricky without the disc. But, for yours it is fine to not install the programs for management issues.

Answer (score 1):

Throw that disk in the trash! It will likely take longer to configure your network using a disk and I wouldn't be suprised if the vendor threw in some adware.

Microsoft actually has a pretty good "How to setup a wireless network" write up.

Check it out:
http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/wirelesssetup.aspx